# accessing Rigidbody2D of RaycastHit2D target?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've got my player sending out a raycast to check another gameobject lets say it's a box, i'd like to access the Rigidbody2D of the box and apply force to it when I hit a key. What are the ways to handle this kind of situation and which ways do you think are most efficient and flexible?

Here's what i'm working with so far.

```
RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(new Vector2(transform.position.x, transform.position.y - 0.6f), new Vector2(transform.position.x, transform.position.y - 1.6f));

if(hit.collider != null && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.E))
        {
             // access gameobject stored to "hit" and AddForce to it's Rigidbody2D??
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `hit` is the type of [RaycastHit2D](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RaycastHit2D.html). RaycastHit2D has the property of `rigidbody`, which returns the [Rigidbody2D component of the object that was hit.](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RaycastHit2D-rigidbody.html) So, you can access it by `hit.rigidbody`.

Another alternative is to use `hit.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>()`, but beware of the performance impact of GetComponent() calls.

To add a force on that Rigidbody2D, you simply provide a Vector2 and an optional force mode with the [AddForce() method](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D.AddForce.html). `hit.rigidbody.AddForce()` would then work.

Also, you might want to consider that you are feeding the correct origin and direction for your Physics2D.Raycast call. It seems like you are trying to tell if there is an object within 1 units of distance in the y-axis. If that is the case, the direction should be Vector2.up, and the distance should be 1.0f, something similar to: `Physics2D.Raycast(new Vector2(transform.position.x, transform.position.y - 0.6f), Vector2.up, 1.0f)`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I supposed the .rigidbody without 2D was throwing me off since they 3D and 2D physics libraries are seperate and won't work with each other.

Comment: Glad that this helped! On most occasions, if a component exclusively has the suffix 2D, it is safe to assume that the component's properties also refer to their 2D counterparts.